# c# Datatable cells updating issue

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I get an error when entering data into the cell in the data table.
Error code: `StackTrace:
at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.get_Count()
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.SetValue(Int32 rowIndex, Object value)
at :line 1633
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()`

Line 1633: TableGridview1.Rows[i].Cells[21].Value = teknikresimim;

Should I bind again after every update cells?

```
for (int i = 0; i < TableGridview1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    #region kolon_adi tanimla
                    string parcano_kolon = Convert.ToString(TableGridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                    string rev_kolon = Convert.ToString(TableGridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                    string op1_kolon = Convert.ToString(TableGridview1.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value);
                    string dwgyolu_kolon = Convert.ToString(TableGridview1.Rows[i].Cells[23].Value);
                    string pdfyolu_kolon = Convert.ToString(TableGridview1.Rows[i].Cells[24].Value);
                    string dizinler = Convert.ToString(TableGridview1.Rows[i].Cells[25].Value);
                    string sirano = Convert.ToString(TableGridview1.Rows[i].Cells[38].Value);
                    #endregion
                    string pdfim = null;
                    string teknikresimim = null;
                    string dwg_kontrol = null;
                        var taskList = new List<Task>
                        {
                            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            {
                                pdfim = PDFdir(parcano_kolon, dizinler, rev_kolon, sirano);
                                TableGridview1.Rows[i].Cells[22].Value = pdfim;
                                TableGridview1.UpdateCellValue(22, i);
                            }),
                            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            {
                                teknikresimim = TeknikDir(parcano_kolon, dizinler)[0];
                                TableGridview1.Rows[i].Cells[21].Value = teknikresimim;
                                TableGridview1.UpdateCellValue(21, i);
                            }),
                            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            {
                                dwg_kontrol = DwgBul(parcano_kolon, rev_kolon, op1_kolon, sirano)[0];
                                TableGridview1.Rows[i].Cells[20].Value = dwg_kontrol;
                                TableGridview1.UpdateCellValue(20, i);
                            })
                        };
                        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
                }
```

Comment: You cannot update GUI elements (or databound data by extension) from a background thread.  This error is by design.

Comment: What error? Can you post a complete error message?

Comment: @Zer0 I tried it. But gave same issue

Comment: @Sinatr; System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
İleti=BindingSource kendisinin veri kaynağı olamaz. DataSource ve DataMember özelliklerini BindingSource'a geri başvuran değerlere ayarlamayın.
Kaynak=System.Windows.Forms
StackTrace:
at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.get_Count()
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.SetValue(Int32 rowIndex, Object value)
at GetBOMList.GetBOMListx.<>c__DisplayClass59_1.<DPKontrolcu>b__3() in GetBOMList.cs:line 1633
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update UI from a different thread.
You need to create a method in the Form code behind to update your datagridview then call it from your Task using an invoke:

*UpdateMethodName*?.Invoke(…)